# How to Output <script> with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i want use PHP to write output `<script></script>` tag. i use code:

```
<?php
echo "test";
echo "<br>";
echo '<script src="http://mywwebiste./mycode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
?>
```

I want it will show:

```
test
<script src="http://mywwebiste./mycode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it only show `test`

Comment: Show were, in the rendered view or in the HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```php
$script = '<script src="http://mywwebiste./mycode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
echo(htmlspecialchars($script));
```

Comment: but when i write to file, it show '&lt; and &gt;. How to when i write to file a.txt, it show full script: <script src="http://mywwebiste./mycode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think you need to use htmlspecialchars_decode while writing into file.